# Repeating a value on the basis of count provided in another cell - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to write a formula where I can generate a number n number of times where n can be the input provided by the user.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT($D2&",", $E2), ), ","))))
```

Ideal output

[image]

Here D2 is the value to be repeated and E2 is the number of times.

So instead of manually using this formula after each last repeated value to generate the next set of repeated values, I want to print the values in one go. I'll be really grateful, if anyone could please provide a way around to do the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(arrayformula(query(flatten(split(rept("|"&D2:D,E2:E),"|")),"select * where Col1 is not null")),SUM(E2:E),1)
```

### explanation

the core of the formula is

```
=arrayformula(iferror(split(rept("|"&D2:D,E2:E),"|")))
```

then, apply flatten with a limitation of rows (ARRAY_CONSTRAIN) equal to the sum of column E, and query only the rows that are not null

Comment: This worked perfectly, could you please explain your answer? Thanks!

Comment: I have added a short explanation, try this formula to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 REPT(D2:D&",", E2:E), ,999^99), ","))))
```